# Tangent vector field of rotating sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a rather simple question that I am stuck with. Given a rotating standard unit sphere, rotating about the $z$-axis with constant angular speed yields a tangent vector field.

I thought I had done this correctly, but the feedback I received pointed out a small error which I don't completely understand, but seems simple.

To calculate the tangent vector field, I used standard spherical coordinates, and thought that I just needed to solve for a vector such that

$$ (\cos(u)\sin(u),\sin(u)\sin(v)) \cdot (x,y) = 0$$

(Since there is no change in $z$ coordinate). Then clearly, $(-\sin(u), \cos(u))$ suffices and so I thought the tangent vector field should be $$(-\sin(u), \cos(u),0)$$
But the feedback questioned whether the magnitude of this vector is always $1$? Because the rotation would be faster the closer it is to the $z$-axis?

So what exactly should the tangent vector field be? Do I just need to add a constant to the components? I'm not too sure how to capture different speeds?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the path $\gamma$ along which a point at height $z$ moves. This path is nothing but a circle with constant $z$-component but whose radius depends on $z$. In other words, it may be parametrized by

$$\gamma(t) = (\alpha \cos(\beta t), \alpha \sin(\beta t), z),$$

where $\beta$ determines the angular speed. If we want, we can find $\alpha$ by solving $1 = \lVert \gamma(t) \rVert^2 = \alpha^2 + z^2$. Now, the tangent field at a point $\gamma(t)$ is given by $\gamma'(t)$ whose magnitude will depend on $\alpha$, which in turn depends on $z$.

Concretely,

$$\gamma'(t) = (-\alpha \beta \sin(\beta t), \alpha \beta \cos (\beta t), 0),$$

so $$\lVert \gamma'(t) \rVert^2 = \alpha^2\beta^2 = (1 - z^2)\beta^2.$$

As a quick sanity check, note that this vanishes for $z = \pm 1$ and has its maximum at $z = 0$.